# CSP - Unsafe-inline or unsafe-eval for specific domain is allowed or not

Tags: web-application, web-browser, xss, content-security-policy

Following is a CSP policy, for example derived sample response headers.

The implementation below allows white-listed domains only in `"script-src"` directive but the `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` directives are also used next `'self'`.

Will this `'unsafe-inline'` / `'unsafe-eval'` be used by all white-listed domains including `'self'` or is it only for `'self'` domain?

```
content-security-policy: 
script-src https://test1dummy.com/
 https://www.google.com/
 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
 https://test2dummy/
 https://test3dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

That CSP directive will allows the use of inline resources, such as inline `<script>` elements, `javascript: URLs`, inline event handlers, and inline `<style>` elements, plus also allows the use of `eval()` and similar methods for creating code from strings.

So... don't bother using CSP. You've just allowed all the bad guys in anyway.

If you change that construct to

```
content-security-policy: 'script-src' https://test1dummy.com/ https://www.google.com/ 'self' https://test2dummy/ https://test3dummy
```

then you've restricted scripts to run from code files on the site itself, plus any of the whitelisted URLS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test1dummy.com/testscript.js"></script>
```

is valid, because test1dummy.com is whitelisted.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mydomain.com/testscript2.js"></script>
```

is valid - but only if mydomain.com is the domain that the CSP headers are running on. If not, then that won't be valid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("Hello admin");</script>
```

This would NOT be valid, now that we've removed the `'inline-unsafe'` option.

If we have a script which is running on a whitelisted domain, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test1dummy.com/testscript.js"></script>
```

and that script itself ends up modifying the DOM and injecting inline script, then that will also be caught by your construct and blocked. And so on, ad-infinitum. Tracking down the script that adds the inline JavaScript is a lot of fun with CSP headers. In the same way, if you leave the `'unsafe-inline'` option in place, any of your whitelisted domains can add inline code to your page.